Clearing Local Storage folder on Electron reset
I have my Electron application ("electron": "^27.3.11", "electron-updater": "^6.1.8")
inside the application the implementation of the updater is such:

going to S3 in AWS to receive the new version file
making cooperation of files (to know if I need to update the app version)
if I do, then download the file and update the application

ipcMain.handle('checkForUpdate', async () => {
..

const server = express();
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'update-server', 'files');
        server.use(express.static(filePath));
        server.listen(5080);
        console.log('File server running at http://localhost:5080/');

        autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
          provider: 'generic',
          url: 'http://localhost:5080/',
        });

        autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
        
}

function cleanUpdates() {
  const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'update-server', 'files');
  fs.readdir(dirPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    files.forEach((file) => {
      fs.unlink(path.join(dirPath, file), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(`Deleted file: ${file}`);
      });
    });
  });
}
        
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (_event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  const dialogOpts = {
    type: 'info',
    buttons: ['Restart'],
    title: 'Application version Update',
    message: process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
    detail:
      'A new version of application has been downloaded. Please Restart the application to apply the updates.',
  };

  cleanUpdates();

  dialog
    .showMessageBox(dialogOpts)
    .then((returnValue) => {
      if (returnValue.response === 0) {
        autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});


update-downloaded - shows the user a popup before restarting the application
cleanUpdates - delete the downloaded files.

I'd also like to delete the ~AppData\Roaming\services\Local Storage\leveldb folder since it keeps the user's token, and I'd like him to re-insert it after the application upgrade is finished.
I couldn't find any good way to do it (most of the solutions gave me the following error: "EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink ...\Roaming\services\LocalStorage\leveldb\000003.log"
